# Execute STRESS Test using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner, stress-testing

It will be greatly appreciated if someone can guide me on how to execute STRESS Tests using JMeter.

We are currently using Loadrunner for Stress/Performance tests & are currently looking to migrate to JMeter.

We have about 300 odd scripts which needs to be migrated, but my concern is with executing scripts. In Loadrunner we make use of Controller component to run 50-60 scripts (which can be configured to start at a certain time, certain volumes etc.). If we want to achieve the same using JMeter, is there any way to do so? Like creating a Test Plan -> Merge all scripts -> execute.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Tried creating a Test Plans, Merge scripts but would like to know the right approach

Answer (score 0):

1. There is [Include Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) which allows you to read external .jmx test script into the current test plan
2. There is the concept of [Test Fragments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and [Module Controllers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) which allows to re-using parts of script without having to copy and paste them
3. If you need to use different volumes and start dates/times for different scripts parts put them under different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

Answer (score 0):

The natural question to ask is why you are not achieving value with LoadRunner?   If you don't fix that issue then switching to Jmeter (or Neoload, or Gatling, or Cloudtest, or ....) isn't going to result in any higher value from your efforts.

Any performance testing tool should return a multiple of the price of the delivery of a test (Labor+tool) in value, every single time.   if not, then this is not a tool problem.   This is a skills/training problem.

And, by the way, the current versions of LoadRunner allow you to run Jmeter tests if that is your goal.

You are trading one tool for another where the feature set does not match between the tools.   Be wary of your path.

Comment: Thank you James! (Big fan of your Perfbytes Podcast!). We've been using LR from 14 yrs or so but it always ends up with "Why not use an Opensource tool?". I know how JMeter works but configuring the test the same way as LR does is what is a challenge.